# Error Installing Libatlas

Tags: software-installation, elementary-os

I am trying to install `libatlas` on my system Elementary Luna OS, using the steps given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/473562/199880).

I get the following error trying this command:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules custom
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 178: /debian/rules: No such file or directory
```

What could be the possible reason for this error?

I found somewhere that it might be fixed by replacing `debian` with `/debiam`, but even that continues to give an error.

What does the tutorial mean by the following:

> type the following from the atlas source subdir:

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Elementary (or anything Debian-based) in front of me to test, but I think you're right to identify that line as the source of the confusion.

The instructions you link have some assumed steps. After you download the source package, you should unpack it (with `tar xvf filename`), and then `cd` into the created directory.

That directory should contain the `debian/rules` subdirectory in question.